# Should I use present or past tense in indirect speech?

Tags: past-tense, backshifting, indirect-speech, future-in-past, will-would

Suppose a person has told me this:

> I will go home.

I want to report what he told me to someone else, but I don’t know whether the condition is still true — that is, whether he has gone home.

Now which version should I use?

> 1. He told me that he **will** go home.
> 2. He told me that he **would** go home.

If the person doing the reporting doesn’t know whether the reported event has happened, which tense should be used here?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You would use "would" if you're describing an event that already happened in the past (i.e., he already went home and you're telling a story or something).

Use "will" if he'll go home in the future, like he's just told you.

Comment: if the person doesn't know whether the event has happened or not. which tense should be used?

Comment: Probably "will". You would use "would" more like if you're approaching everything with a past perspective, like you're telling a story of what happened in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Choose "He told me that he would go home" unless you wish to show emphasis, in which case "will" is possible, to emphasize that he *will* do it despite some obstacle.

Answer (score 0):

In reported speech is important to consider if the event or situation is still relevant to the time of speaking. For example I told you Ann lives with his parents ( Ann lives with his parent). It is not necessary to change tense time.